# Метка перегрузка

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, переименование-метки

Есть метка [перегрузка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0). Она часто используется вместе с [операторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b).

Мое чувство прекрасного говорит что метка должна называться [перегрузка-операторов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2), а "перегрузка" и "операторы" надо использовать для перегрузки функций, тока в электросети, т.е. по отдельности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перегрузку сделал синонимом к перегрузке-операторов. Метку [операторы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b) оставил, так как по ней есть вопросы, например, по [python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python).